# Dependencies nightmare

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I'm trying to install openbts but it requires a bunch of dependencies, some of which fail:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libboost-all-dev : Depends: libboost-python-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libsqlite3-dev : Depends: libsqlite3-0 (= 3.7.9-2ubuntu1) but 3.7.9-2ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
 sqlite3 : Depends: libsqlite3-0 (= 3.7.9-2ubuntu1) but 3.7.9-2ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
```

I figure that I can structure the command in such a way as to ignore the different versions on the sqlite stuff and install it anyways (is this okay?) but what I don't understand is what's going on with libboost.

```
apt-get install libboost-all-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libboost-all-dev : Depends: libboost-python-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

apt-get install libboost-python-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libboost-python-dev : Depends: libboost-python1.46-dev but it is not going to be installed
```

I thought I might have a different version installed:

```
apt-get remove libboost-all-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libboost-all-dev is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 163 not upgraded.
```

same for this:

```
apt-get remove libboost-python-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libboost-python-dev is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 163 not upgraded.



apt-get install libboost-python1.46-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libboost-python1.46-dev : Depends: python-dev but it is not going to be installed
```

Could somebody please explain what is going on?

Comment: Running 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

If you type the following in to a Terminal window it might help

<s>sudo apt-get -f install libboost-python-dev</s>

```
 sudo apt-get -f install openbts
```

The `-f` option forces `apt-get to down load the required dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

try the build-dep option that's the best option for getting out of the dependencies nightmare.
`sudo apt-get build-dep <package-name>` (openbts in your case)

This would automatically build all the required dependencies.